# Get value of textbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox for users to enter a new email address.  I have a button that calls a script.   In the script I need to access several different elements of the page.  The first couple of elements, that were sent as parameters to the page (via PHP) work fine, but I do not get the right result when I try to get the value of the text box.

This is my HTML:

```
<p>Please enter the new email</p>
<input type="email" id="newemail" value="enter new email here">
```

and this is my JS:

```
var userid=$('#userId').val();
var oldEmail=$('#useremail').val();
var newEmail=$('#newemail').val();

//I have also tried with var newEmail=document.getElementById("newemail").value
//with no difference in the result

alert(userid + " " + oldEmail + " " + newemail);
```

The alert prints out :

```
5 Sammy [object HTMLInputElement]
```

I note that it is printing neither the old value of the text box nor the new value which the user entered.  How to I get it to get that value?

Comment: ahhh JS is case sensitive...thank you all...so much for doing this before breakfast!  Will accept answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. `newemail` should be `newEmail`.

When referencing `newemail` you are accessing `window.newemail` which will by default return the DOM element with ID `newemail`. Calling `.toString()` on that DOM element produces `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

Change the `alert` to:

```
alert(userid + " " + oldEmail + " " + newEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is `newEmail`, but in alert you are using `newemail`, they are case sensitive.

Then how `newemail` is working, because since it is the id of an element the property will be added as a window elements property

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
alert(userid + " " + oldEmail + " " + newemail);
```

by

```
    alert(userid + " " + oldEmail + " " + newEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is a typo?

```
alert(userid + " " + oldEmail + " " + newemail);
```

doesnt fit the variable declarations:

```
var newEmail=$('#newemail').val();
```